# How to prove that there is a differentiable function $f$ such that $[f(x)]^{153}+f(x)+x=0$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Prove that there is a differentiable function $f$ such that $[f(x)]^{153}+f(x)+x=0$ for all $x$. Furthermore, find $f'$ in terms of $f$.

To me I just write $y$ instead of all $f(x)$ and find that $x=-(y^{153}+y)$ If I just derive that would that be the solution of this question? If not what should i do to answer it appropriately.

Comment: Please write titles that describe the problem you wish to solve rather than the course title.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Can you advise me a description for this problem? Because I am a bit confused about the description.

Comment: I just placed the question in the title (while avoiding the command form, which is interpreted as rude on this site).

Comment: Oh okay now it is obvious to me. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

If $x = -[f(x)]^{153} - f(x)$,
then $g(x) = -x^{153} - x$ is the inverse function of $f(x)$.
Then if you prove $g(x)$ is differentiable, what does it tell about its inverse function ?

Comment: Then it's inverse is differentiable?

Comment: Yes, you may look at exercise 12.14 for a sample problem [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~j.e.hickman/161%20Homework/Homework%209%20Solution.pdf)

Comment: @HouseBT  Unless $g'$ vanishes.

Comment: Thank you so much ^^

Comment: Np :) hope you do see why $g$ is the inverse of $f$.. (Initially I had a problem visualizing..)

Comment: Yeah, I see it. Actually, that was my way of solving it at first. Just I couldn't get to the end :)